# Prove that the inner product $\langle f,g\rangle= \int f(t)g(t) \, dt $ satisfies the property positive definiteness

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, positive-definite

In $C[a,b]$, define the product

$\langle f,g\rangle= \int f(t)g(t) \, dt $.

Show that this product satisfies the property, $\langle f,f\rangle$ is greater than zero for all non zero $f$ using a non graphical proof and no  δs to explain your answer.

Although this question was claimed to be a duplicate of [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192354/prove-l2-inner-product-satisfies-positivity), I would like an explanation without  δs.

Comment: I do not understand  "δ" in the answer to that question above. Could you explain the problem without deltas? @DavidK

Comment: @DavidK: If that is your understanding (which I agree with), how is it possible for $f(c) = 0$ ? Since $f$ is continuous on a compact interval, it attains it's min, max i.e $f(c)$ cannot be zero as $c \in [a,b]$.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood We certainly do not both assume that. I merely assume that $f$ is not zero _everywhere_ in $[a,b]$. I believe that is what "non-zero" function means. Perhaps OP can explain that for their context, I am wrong.

Comment: @DavidK: As soon as I was writing my response, I realized where I had made a mistake with the problem. You are definitely correct.

Comment: @FaraadArmwood No problem! I'm happy we resolved our confusion. I removed some comments that now seem unnecessary.

Comment: Proofs using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ reasoning are foundational for standard analysis, that is, they're part of the "standard" way we define $\int\ldots dt$ in the first place, so it's a bit strange that they're not in the permitted toolbox for a question like this. Perhaps if there were some hints about what proof techniques _are_ permitted, this question could receive an adequate answer that is truly different from the other question's answer.

Comment: I decided not to vote on this question (either to close or to leave open). However, I still recommend the asker closely review the question that this one is said to be a duplicate of.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of Linear Algebra, it's *obvious* that $\int_a^b f^2(x)dx$ is a positive quantity for a continuous nonzero $f(x)$. So as a Linear Algebra question, it's a bit off-topic.

For an analysis person, it's a little different. A "proof" would go like this. If $f(x)$ is continuous, so is $f^2(x)$. If $f^2(x)$ is nonzero, then there is a point where it's positive. It is known for continuous functions that if it's positive at a point, then it's positive over some interval that contains that point - there's a common $\epsilon\text{-}\delta$ argument that proves that. Over that interval, the integral is positive and it is therefore positive over $\left[a,b\right]$.